# Extract arbitrary subtotals from 2D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have 2D arrays of counts from which I need to extract a sequence of arbitrary subtotals. In this example they are subtotal *columns*. Each subtotal is the sum of an arbitrary collection of the base columns, represented by a tuple of *addend-indices*:

```
>>> A
[[11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
 [21, 22, 23, 24, 25]
 [31, 32, 33, 34, 35]]

>>> subtotal_addend_idxs
((0, 1), (1, 2, 3), (3, 4))

>>> desired_result
[[23, 39, 29]
 [43, 69, 49]
 [63, 99, 69]]
```

The best code I have for this so far is this:

```
subtotal_addend_idxs = ((0, 1), (1, 2, 3), (3, 4))
np.hstack(
    tuple(
        np.sum(A[:, subtotal_addend_idxs], axis=1, keepdims=True)
        for addend_idxs in self._column_addend_idxs
    )
)
```

Is there a clever way I can do this with a single `numpy` call/expression where I don't need a `for` loop creating a tuple of individual subtotal columns?

Note that the addend-indices are arbitrary; not all indices need appear in a subtotal, the indices do not necessarily appear in increasing order, and the same index can appear in more than one subtotal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`np.add.reduceat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html) :

```
lens = [len(n) for n in subtotal_addend_idxs]
c = np.concatenate(subtotal_addend_idxs)
output = np.add.reduceat(A[:,c], np.cumsum([0]+lens)[:-1], axis=1)
```

**Output:**

```
array([[23, 39, 29],
       [43, 69, 49],
       [63, 99, 69]], dtype=int32)
```

Remark: a faster option for `np.concatenate` would be `np.fromiter(itertools.chain(*subtotal_addend_idxs), dtype=int)`.

Comment: Hmm, this is a very interesting approach, so basically create a new single array of _all_ the addend columns, and then `reduceat()` them in each subtotal group. That's a clever idea :)

Comment: @scanny Changing order of indices is a common practise in `numpy` arrays, don't hesitate to try it more often :)

Answer (score 0):

Since we cannot use `np.take`, here is my solution (there is still a for loop in the `lambda` function ...)

```
test = np.array([[11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
                 [21, 22, 23, 24, 25],
                 [31, 32, 33, 34, 35]])
inds = ((0, 1), (1, 2, 3), (3, 4))

fake_take = lambda array,inds:[np.sum(array[list(ind)]) for ind in inds]
np.apply_along_axis(lambda x:fake_take(x,inds),1,test)
```